# Duplicate records created on certain actions in a Heroku Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, duplicates, race-condition

I'm having an issue where duplicate records are being created in what is seemingly a race condition, since I run a dupe check hooked into before create.

In this case, I'm creating prospects out of leads. The applicable code is here:

```
def process_multiple
  @leads = Lead.find(lead_params[:lead_ids])

  user_target = User.find(lead_params[:target_user_id])
  @leads.each do |lead|
    pros = Prospect.find_or_create_by( lead: lead, prospectable: user_target )
    pros.update_attributes(:first_name => lead.first_name,
                           :last_name => lead.last_name,
                           :middle_name => lead.middle_name,
                           :salutation => lead.salutation)
  end

  redirect_to action: 'index'
end
```

The duplication check that is run on before_create is as follows

```
def duplication_check
  dup_prospect = Prospect.find_by_prospectable_id_and_prospectable_type_and_lead_id(self.prospectable_id, self.prospectable_type, self.lead_id)
  if dup_prospect.blank?
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Below is an example of the duplicate records that are created. Note, the second column is a "lead id" which the prospect is based off of. There should never be multiple prospects from the same lead assigned to the same user.

[image: example of the duplicate records created]

As you can see from the image above, duplicate records are being created. And given the timing, it seems it's a race condition of sorts.

My two questions are:

1) What can I do to create an absolute firewall to prevent this from happening? Obviously a dupe check is not enough.
2) More importantly, why are duplicate records being created in the first place, especially since, as I understand it, the front end servers of Heroku are single-threaded?

Note: We do, right now, use multiple dynos, but this was happening even when we were using the single front end dyno during dev.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you attempting to implement an upsert / create-if-not-exists?

Comment: @CraigRinger No, I'm just processing items from a form and turning "leads" to "prospects." For whatever reason, I'm regularly getting dupes, and I have no idea why a race condition is being created.

Comment: @CraigRinger FYI - the find_or_create_by was added prior to adding the dupe check in before_create to try to solve the dupe issue. Needless to say, it didn't work.

Comment: You may want to do the de-duping in your dictionary/array before doing the insertion requests to make sure that you aren't trying to process records that are almost similar but actually have a slight difference. At least as a test on the single dyno just to cover this base.

Comment: @liam It's definitely not a dupe in the array, I've checked the array in its raw form. The records are duped based on the source lead and associated user - there's no way to have a "similar" record. It either is a prospect that came from the lead and is assigned to that user, or not. This has been extremely frustrating. I think we've started to track it down to a potential chrome submission bug, however.